# Locating the source of Forbidden message

Tags: 7

When I login I see these "Forbidden" messages. How to track the source of this message?

Also I've enabled these settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check Drupal and webserver logs? What does they say?

Comment: @FiNeX I could find only single message: " Session opened for ws-admin." in Drupal recent log messages and nothing in the web-server error log

Comment: Did you already check the file system permissions? Are you using modules to restrict node/entity access?

Comment: I've don'e `chmod -R 777` but same problem. Let me check restricting nodes.

Comment: As it's not a warning, it may be someone who put that in there with drupal_set_message().

Comment: Try to search `Forbidden` in your code base. You may be able to find where it from....

Answer (score 0):

I started disabling modules one by one and [rest_auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_auth) was actually causing it though it was  not being used. Simply disabling solved it. And yes it does not contain any word "**forbidden**".